# Ruby gems not seen within system call

Tags: php, ruby, rubygems, system

I have a problem where I can run a script with `require 'mysql2'` in it on the console fine, however within a php system call on the same machine it won't work.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this please?

Gareth

Comment: Can you be a little bit more explicit plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might have `GEM_HOME` set in your own environment, but the user PHP is running as doesn't have the same set.

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page83